# how to wordpress posts complete permalinks by using mysql query based on permalink structure

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want get all post permalinks based on permalink structure `'/%category%/%postname%/'`  this is my permalink structure where i want get post complete permalink by using mysql query where following my permalink structure.

```
SELECT wpp.post_title, wpp.guid, wpp.post_date,
       REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( REPLACE( wpo.option_value, '%year%', DATE_FORMAT(wpp.post_date,'%Y') ), '%monthnum%', DATE_FORMAT(wpp.post_date, '%m') ), '%day%', DATE_FORMAT(wpp.post_date, '%d') ), '%postname%', wpp.post_name ) AS permalink
  FROM wp_posts wpp
  JOIN wp_options wpo
    ON wpo.option_name = 'permalink_structure'
 WHERE wpp.post_type = 'post'
   AND wpp.post_status = 'publish'
 ORDER BY wpp.post_date DESC;
```

I have followed this but not sure i ddint find my permalink structure format. any helps